# Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have Joomla! 1.7.2 Stable and when I try to Log in to administration area I get this error

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/shomos1/public_html/portal/libraries/joomla/user/user.php on line 822
```

this is the error line in my user.php

```
    public function load($id)
    {
        // Create the user table object

        $table  = $this->getTable();
var_dump($table);
        // Load the JUserModel object based on the user id or throw a warning.
        if (!$table->load($id)) {
            JError::raiseWarning('SOME_ERROR_CODE', JText::sprintf('JLIB_USER_ERROR_UNABLE_TO_LOAD_USER', $id));
            return false;
        }

        // Set the user parameters using the default XML file.  We might want to
        // extend this in the future to allow for the ability to have custom
        // user parameters, but for right now we'll leave it how it is.

        $this->_params->loadString($table->params);

        // Assuming all is well at this point lets bind the data
        $this->setProperties($table->getProperties());

        return true;
    }
}
```

I am not good in Joomla and I can't understand what is the problem there 
please need help what can I do to solve this problem
Thanks

Comment: to what is `$table` set at this moment?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get you question how to know what is the $table set how to check

Comment: OK sorry you mean this $table = $this->getTable();

Comment: please write `var_dump($table);` before the error line and give me the return value.

Comment: I got the same error but with bool(false) before the error
bool(false)
Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/shomos1/public_html/portal/libraries/joomla/user/user.php on line 823

Comment: before the error line it gives me bool(false)

Comment: The error is: getTable() should not return false. But I can't understand why, when lookng at the source: http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/scmsvn/?action=browse&path=/development/tags/1.5.x/1.5.23/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php&view=markup Sorry; I can't help you :-(

Comment: Thanks for your try bwoebi

Comment: I've found the best thing for debugging Joomla sites (especially when you're developing custom components/modifying source) is to install a PHP debugger, such as XDebug, and a GUI tool for debugging (such as Eclipse for PHP). Then, you can step through and examine exactly what is going on.

Comment: Yeah I'm not seeing where a `false` return value would be coming from either. Seems to me like that code should check `!empty($table)` if that's the case.

Comment: hi jordojuice how to check this !empty($table) should I put this before the error line to check or what

Comment: Hay I have the same site working perfect on another server and I can log in to the admin and everything is fine there, when I changed the server I backup all the files on the old server and I put them on the news one I edited the configuration file and everything working fine but I can not log in to the admin area with this error do the server has anything to do with this error

Comment: Upgrade to Joomla 2.5.11 !!!! Makes me cringe seeing people still using 1.6 or 1.7

Comment: Thanks all of you guys your answers really helped me a lot I solved the problem by taking another copy from the old server by Akeeba this helped me a lot Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default com_user component is conflicting with your component so you must rename your component files they must  not have name "user" ...